# Best approach for forecasting in this typical case

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, prediction, forecasting

I am building a time series forecasting model. The data I have has one variable 'amount' which is the freight charge for the material transported. I have 10 years of data in the monthly format. 
The challenge here is the freight bill amount of a month does not necessarily reflect the amount charged for the materials transported in that month only. Sometimes, the materials are transported in fragments and are charged in next 2-3 months and those bills get unexpectedly high disturbing the time series pattern randomly. For ex., if I have Bill of Mar 2017, it may have some amount from Jan and Feb as well.
I tried ARIMA and got a MAPE of 40%. I tried Croston method and MAPE varies in 23%-32%. Would a rolling window forecast help here? Or any other suggestion, please.

Edit 1  - I have added the data set (Year 2008 - 2016). I managed to get monthly revenue data from my professor. So, I tried bivariate model using TSLM function which gave me R-squared of 67%. It is way lower than what he is expecting.

```
yearmon Paid.Amount revenue
8-Jan   1936599.88  2937700
8-Feb   1844486.91  3074900
8-Mar   1735122.05  3690000
8-Apr   1279519.88  3097700
8-May   1539967.05  3077100
8-Jun   1231146.36  3352300
8-Jul   1162991.84  2400600
8-Aug   1263879.69  3050000
8-Sep   1244323     3899200
8-Oct   1424559.93  3533000
8-Nov   898217.92   2723400
8-Dec   1085732.89  4055400
9-Jan   1029221.93  2486600
9-Feb   876441.65   2101400
9-Mar   880441.37   2998400
9-Apr   722948.96   1996500
9-May   958005.43   1807400
9-Jun   610958.71   2332300
9-Jul   695254.7    2280900
9-Aug   756439.4    2020500
9-Sep   926815.65   3231500
9-Oct   924445.94   2294200
9-Nov   830403.35   2782700
9-Dec   925630.38   3246000
10-Jan  700777.04   2135400
10-Feb  548469.87   1962800
10-Mar  696256.42   2641700
10-Apr  695798.95   2025700
10-May  704871.44   1996500
10-Jun  728251.49   2590600
10-Jul  664962.06   1984500
10-Aug  727306.82   2421300
10-Sep  720462.6    3084000
10-Oct  999328.49   2874300
10-Nov  950702.54   3069200
10-Dec  984782.65   3704600
11-Jan  864608.73   2976800
11-Feb  711251.25   2981700
11-Mar  1145917.13  3552500
11-Apr  844124.97   2684600
11-May  865543.97   2667900
11-Jun  883278.98   2707300
11-Jul  834070.34   2493400
11-Aug  1116866.09  3023300
11-Sep  1151143.55  3581100
11-Oct  1351395.01  3217800
11-Nov  1118297.76  3239000
11-Dec  1374179.71  4637800
12-Jan  989117.07   3313000
12-Feb  927470.54   2530600
12-Mar  1069185.01  3496500
12-Apr  1009312.54  2403000
12-May  1022559.87  2638500
12-Jun  961677.71   3246000
12-Jul  834523.02   2272300
12-Aug  1081960.39  2886000
12-Sep  1107927.72  3890100
12-Oct  1093140.22  2682100
12-Nov  1310195.61  3292000
12-Dec  1344106.8   4960100
13-Jan  1030537.47  3114800
13-Feb  911014.19   3121300
13-Mar  930071.08   3490900
13-Apr  890881.25   2542800
13-May  876954.67   2354800
13-Jun  915720.02   3382700
13-Jul  908514.48   2310000
13-Aug  1043391.95  3087300
13-Sep  1093640.35  3869300
13-Oct  1197865.65  3170800
13-Nov  1216958.3   3875300
13-Dec  1461027.39  5801000
14-Jan  1242969.8   2970300
14-Feb  1054214.44  3595300
14-Mar  1171459.28  4012800
14-Apr  990720.44   2916700
14-May  891504.63   2794200
14-Jun  936850.28   3501000
14-Jul  985009.09   2689100
14-Aug  1229039.59  3199000
14-Sep  1272825     4605200
14-Oct  1274631.05  3649500
14-Nov  1493390.61  4171600
14-Dec  1810523.68  6043700
15-Jan  1225779.44  3526300
15-Feb  1066156.45  3374900
15-Mar  1158659.52  4141200
15-Apr  1085067.52  3058800
15-May  1243264.14  2932700
15-Jun  1375846.69  3581800
15-Jul  1230235.7   3210200
15-Aug  1242221.75  3348200
15-Sep  1372310.27  4443200
15-Oct  1489968.27  3254200
15-Nov  1520498.52  4086200
15-Dec  1873884.03  7100500
16-Jan  1225046.91  2922600
16-Feb  1169703.36  3314600
16-Mar  1345611.1   4597900
16-Apr  1182650.19  3057000
16-May  1368704.21  3599400
16-Jun  1485036.6   4292300
16-Jul  1194201.57  3189600
16-Aug  1378889.12  3289200
16-Sep  1533056.53  4666700
16-Oct  1398696.43  3837600
16-Nov  1742668.73  4234900
16-Dec  2162712.41  6418700
```

I would greatly appreciate if anyone can suggest a better approach to predict the Paid.Amount.

Thanks.

Comment: I like Hyndman's forecast package. It handles the data well and provides a suite of forecasting options and corresponding plots.

Comment: Post your dataset

Comment: @TomReilly  - I have updated the question and have the data set. Looking forward to your suggestion based on the data set.

Comment: @RyanMorton - I did try the forecast package but nothing good came out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Sanket,

You can download all of the results [here](http://www.autobox.com/client/Sanket/Sanket.zip). Details.htm is the audit of the model that was built. The model supports this with a lag variable in the revenue variable showing that there is a delay on its impact on Y(paid). A time trend beginning at period 1 going down and another going up at period 19 are not explained by revenue and are due to an omitted causal.  Do you have an explanation?  If so, then identify and add that factor as a causal.

There is weak seasonality, but Autobox identified certain months as showing importance (ie 8,10 and 11 all higher than average).

An AR2 with lag of 1 and 2 will also play a role into using more lags of revenue out to lag 4.(see rhside.txt showing the pure right hand equation with all of the factors expressed as a pure regression.

An outlier was identified at period 17 and a level shift at 89 increasing volume(again not explained by revenue so maybe another omitted causal).

[image: Equation]

You did not provide forecasts of revenue so we allowed Autobox (a software I am part of) to build a model and forecast the future values. A possible enhancement could be made to provide better forecasts of revenue from your side as that is a model/forecast too!   The revenue variable did not stay in the model and then we constrained it and it turned out to be highly significant anyway as the model evolved to include some deterministic variables and AR factors.

The bivariate normalized plot of revenue and paid show a strong POSITIVE relationship, but just know that you are looking at contemporaneous relationship where they may be impacts at lags as well.

[image: Bivariate Normalized Scatter Plot]

The bivariate line graph supports this lagged relationship between x and y with a bump in y a few periods later.

[image: Bivariate Normalized Line plot]

Here is the forecast[image]

Comment: Thanks, Tom, for the detailed analysis. I can see that R-squared reached 90% which is very good. I greatly appreciate your effort but I am not able to understand what process is running behind this modeling. I see that you have used your software to do the forecast but I have no idea how to achieve this in R. If you have suggestions on what functions and approach I can utilize in R to achieve good results, I will be grateful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: R-squared is not a good beacon....the more variables you put in the higher it goes.  We have a version of our software in R so you are good.  To reproduce our results, you need to create dummy variables for the two trends (ie 0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3) that are listed.  You need to account for the ARIMA component.  You need to account for the level shift (ie 0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,etc).  You need to account for the seasonal pulse (ie 0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0 etc). You need to create a lag of the causal.  You need to account for the outlier (ie 0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The following is the initial approach that I consistently use for relatively simple 1 step ahead monthly forecasts. More time could be spent afterward to try to get some of the harder characteristics of this problem modeled.

In this case I did the following:

1. Remove the first two years of data.  There is a clear regime
   change or at least change in trend that doesn't appear to be likely 
   for near term forecasts.
2. I transformed the data using a lognormal transformation.  Just a
   quick eyeball of the data suggested to me there might be some
   nonlinear growth happening.
3. Breakup the data into a section for initial fitting, validation, and
   testing (in this case, I did not set aside data for testing).
4. Prepare a collection of models you want to evaluate.  The criteria I
   chose to evaluate them on is the MSE for 1 step ahead forecasts.
5. Perform a cross-validation procedure for these models.  The
   following two links explain the process that can work well for
   time-series. [Time-Series Cross Validation - 1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection) [Time-Series
   Cross Validation - 2](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/)
6. I chose to select the model with the lowest cross-validation error. 
   If I had kept a test data set, I would try forecasting on it to
   confirm the performance is as good or nearly as good as during the
   cross-validation period.
7. In the validation period for the optimal model,rsqr is 83.4%.  The
   MAE is $86,478.  The MAPE is 6.9%.

The optimal model from various Seasonal ARIMA models I tested, ended up being:
[0,0,1] [1,1,1]12
So MA = 1, SAR = 1, SDiff = 1, and SMA = 1 where season is 12.

[image: Cross Validation Results]